# Leaving 2 blank pages upon compilation

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, blank-page

I am trying to add a non numbered chapter. I have done so successfully for other chapters using the same code.

The code I am using is:

```
\clearpage
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\include{Chapters/Nomenclature}
```

However, at the start of the chapter it is automatically leaving the blank pages.

Does anybody know the reason. I am sorry for not adding the setup file.

Comment: You really should provide a minimal example including preamble. We for one thing, does not know which class you are using.

Comment: Don't use `\include` it inserts empty pages. Use `\input`.

Comment: or add `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline` to the included file

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: It partially works with your suggestion. Now it is leaving 1 page. :(

Comment: @SiddharthModi, remove `\clearpage`.

Comment: What is in `Chapters/Nomenclature.tex`?

Comment: @Sigur: removing clear page is not helping. For some reason there is a page gap between last chapter and when this begins.

Comment: @SiddharthModi, I guess that you are using `openright` option in the document class and so new chapters will always start on the right pages.

Comment: I wish it was that. Anyways, hopefully sort it out soon.

Comment: @ Sigur: After your comment I tried using open right. All the chapters start from right page. However, the nomenclature chapter mentioned hare leaves two page and starts on the left page.

Comment: the question seems to be abandoned and without further information (MWE) nobody can tell what is going on and why an empty page is introduced. Right now, the Q is unclear.